# Selenium parse elements to string

Tags: ruby, selenium

My goal is to dynamically get website content created by Javascript. I have the following code:

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get "https://gls-group.eu/AT/de/paket-verfolgen?match=00000000000"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)
js_code = "return document.getElementsByTagName('div')"
elements = browser.execute_script(js_code)

puts elements

browser.close
```

The output is:

```
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e4c920>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e4c770>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e4c230>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e55650>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e55848>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e57e58>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e57c00>
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x4e57a08>
```

and so on. How do I get the `div`s?

Comment: try `puts elements.to_s` or `puts elements.html` i don't remeber correct variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`browser.execute_script(js_code)` gives all the html elements as you asked as instances of `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` class. Write as below using method [`Selenium::WebDriver::Element#text`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#text-instance_method) to get the content of those `div` elements :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get "https://gls-group.eu/AT/de/paket-verfolgen?match=00000000000"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 20)
js_code = "return document.getElementsByTagName('div')"
elements = browser.execute_script(js_code)
elements.each{|e| puts e.text }
```