# How could I set value to an disabled input element

Tags: selenium

I want to set the date value by selenium.

Which is a datapicker element with disabled attribute

This script doesn't work for me

```
@driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('departureDate').setAttribute('value', '2015-09-07')")
```

I even couldn't get value by this `@driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('departureDate').getAttribute('value')")`

However I can get inspect the value by

```
[50] pry(#<Tiger>)> el = @driver.find_element(:id, "departureDate")
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x3f5415a2252a05c4 id="{f12a4095-6326-d241-b22d-aca9c03918e3}">
[51] pry(#<Tiger>)> el.attribute("value")
"2015-09-18"
```

But how can I set the value with `2015-09-07`

I'm working on this page `https://m.tigerair.com/booking/search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)()** *by supplying [css path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648412/how-to-generate-css-path-with-javascript-or-jquery/32306303#32306303)* to get tag information, and then add this [js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java/31293581#31293581)-code to selenium as a string.

```
var taginfo = document.querySelector('input#departureDate');
var date = taginfo.value;
console.log(date);
```

to change try this.

```
taginfo.value.replace('2015-09-08');
```

Comment: How could I add this   js library to ruby selenium, thanks

Comment: read js code as String and supply to executeScript()  @driver.execute_script(jsAsString);     [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430773/how-to-use-javascript-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java/31293581#31293581)

Comment: js_code = "return document.querySelector('input#departureDate')"
tagInfo = browser.execute_script(js_code)  date = tagInfo .attribute("value")
    [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869034/selenium-parse-elements-to-string)

Comment: Shouldn't i include the js lib in the website  or do something with Ruby-binding selenium ? but the website is not owned by me.

Comment: no need to include any js lib already this querySelector() is available in browsers.